# How to reset values in for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11

I need help figuring out where my code went wrong. I want to reset the values for the loop so that it isn't compiling because my output right now is using past input values in current calculation whereas I want the output to be different every time as though it is the firs time running the code. The code works fine when I don't use the while loop, but then I have to rerun the program each time. I want the output to prompt a new input every time, but not use past inputs in the new calculations. I know I'm not explaining it very well, but I'm just sort of lost. Anything helps!

This is my problem:

> An approximate value of pi can be calculated using the series given
>   below:
>
> pi = 4 · [ 1 – 1/3 + 1/5 – 1/7 + 1/9 ... + (–1 ^ n)/(2n + 1) ]
>
> Write a C++ program to calculate the approximate value of pi using
>   this series. The program takes an input n that determines the number
>   of terms in the approximation of the value of pi and outputs the
>   approximation. Include a loop that allows the user to repeat this
>   calculation for new values n until the user says she or he wants to
>   end the program.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  double sum=0;

  cout << "Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):\n";
  cin >> n;

  if (n == 0)
    {
   return 0;
    }

  while (n != 0)
   {
     { for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
         if (i%2==0)
           {
             sum += 1.0/(2*i+1);
           }
         else
           {
             sum += -1.0/(2*i+1);
           }
       }

    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << "The approximation is " << sum*4 << " using " << n << " terms." << endl;
     }
    cout << "Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):\n";
    cin >> n;
    }

return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

This is what the output should be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not reset `sum` before entering the `for` loop. Just add

```
sum=0;
```

before the `for` line.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 2.67 = 6.67 - 4.00.

You want your program to compute a `sum` for several values of `n`.
The sum must be initialized to 0 at the beginning of each calculation, inside the `while` loop.

Actually, it should even be declared there.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't require you to define variables at the start of a function, so it is perfectly legal to write:

```
while (n != 0)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
```

this would solve your problem. Alternatively, if you want to keep the declaration of sum at the top of the function, just change your code to

```
while (n != 0)
{
    sum = 0.0;
```